# unnecessary return keyword in complied Javascript when writing CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, return

This code is the coffee script and when translated into JS it gives me "return" keyword before _load function. I have tried moving around functions and changing the loops into one-liner doesn't seem to help
please help

```
(->
  resourceCache = {}
  loading = []
  readyCallbacks = []
  # load image url or array of image urls
  load = (urlOrArr) ->
    if (urlOrArr instanceof Array)
      for url in urlOrArr
        _load(url)
    else
      _load(urlOrArr)

  _load = (url) ->
    if(resourceCache[url])
      resourceCache[url]
    else
      img = new Image()
      img.onload = ->
        resourceCache[url] = img
        if(isReady())
          (func) -> func() for el in readyCallbacks
      resourceCache[url] = false
      img.src = url

.
.
.





)()
```

here is the js

```
(function() {
    var load, loading, readyCallbacks, resourceCache, _load;
    resourceCache = {};
    loading = [];
    readyCallbacks = [];
    load = function(urlOrArr) {
      var url, _i, _len, _results;
      if (urlOrArr instanceof Array) {
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = urlOrArr.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
          url = urlOrArr[_i];
          _results.push(_load(url));
        }
        return _results;
      } else {
        return _load(urlOrArr);
      }
    };
    return _load = function(url) {
      var img;
      if (resourceCache[url]) {
        return resourceCache[url];
      } else {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
          resourceCache[url] = img;
```

Answer (score 2):

In [coffeescript](/questions/tagged/coffeescript) [*"Everything is an Expression (at least, as much as possible)"*](http://coffeescript.org/#expressions). And the last expression of a function is its return value.

To enforce that, the compiler silently add implicit `return` statement at the end of each execution branch of a function.

So, the `return _load ...` in JS is expected as the last statement of your outer function is that function definition (`_load = (url) -> ...`).

---

If for some reason, you really don't want the inner function being returned, you have to add an extra statement at the end of your function. Please compare those various cases:

### *1: Implicit return (your case)*

```
->
    "Outer function"

    inner = ->
        "Inner function
```

Compiles into

```
(function() {
  (function() {
    "Outer function";
    var inner;
    return inner = function() {
      return "Inner function";
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

### *2: With explicit return statement*

```
->
    "Outer function"

    inner = ->
        "Inner function"

    return
```

Compiles into

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
(function() {
  (function() {
    "Outer function";
    var inner;
    inner = function() {
      return "Inner function";
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

That extra return statement will in fact made the outer function return value `undefined`. If you want, you can make that explicit by using `return undefined` or even simply `undefined` instead of the bare `return`. The compiled code will be slightly different (explicit `return void 0`) but the *behavior* will be the same.

### *3: explicit `undefined` expression*

```
->
    "Outer function"

    inner = ->
        "Inner function"

    undefined
    # or `return undefined`
```

Compiles into

```
(function() {
  function() {
    "Outer function";
    var inner;
    inner = function() {
      return "Inner function";
    };
    return void 0;
  };
}).call(this);
```

Comment: The last expression is the return value.

Comment: it makes sense but still not working . you did not read my question right _LOAD is not inside of LOAD as you answered. _LOAD and LOAD are both inside IIFE though